# Doctrine Searchable with non-ASCII characters

Tags: doctrine, non-ascii-characters, searchable

I have text in Turkish language: "selam günaydın". Doctrine
searchable converts it to keywords in table:
-selam
-guenaydin

So "guenaydin" was saved in table as keyword "günaydın" so when
somebody writes in search "günaydın" he gets nothing - what can I
do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

You should first use the analyze() method of the Doctrine_Search_Analyzer_Standard class, in order to convert the incoming search string to the format of the index table.